# Creating Sub Domains in Umbraco Website

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, umbraco, web-deployment

My website URL is like this www.mydomain.com. And this URL is bound to my Home Node.Now I have a sub node named "test" .I want the url of this node to be like www.test.mydomain.com.Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the node you want to assign a URL to, and select "Manage Hostnames":

[image]

Then, using the popup form, input your URL, choose a language and select "Add new domain" to save the change:

[image]

<sub>Hope these images have come out okay, as I can't see them.</sub>